# Proper words of Durood-e-Ibraheem

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, prophet-ibrahim, salawat

Assalamu Alaikum.

I have heard two versions of the Durood-e-Ibraheem. After the first Innaka Hameedum Majeed some say Wa Baarik ala or Allahumma Baarik ala.

Is it: اللهم صل على محمد وعلى آل محمد كما صليت على إبراهيم وعلى آل إبراهيم إنك حميد مجيد اللهم بارك or اللهم صل على محمد وعلى آل محمد كما صليت على إبراهيم وعلى آل إبراهيم إنك حميد مجيد وبارك على

Please help, will my prayers be accepted by either one of them?

Answer (score 3):

Durood Shareef is often referred to in Arabic as *as-salāh al-Ibrāhīmiyyah* (Arabic: الصلاه الإبراهيميه) or [salawāt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salawat). There are two commonly-used forms that you can use in your prayers after reciting the *tashahhud* just before ending your prayers. The full form of the tashahhud can be found in Islam Q&A's article "[Wording of the tashahhud and sending blessings on the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)](https://islamqa.info/en/98031)."

The first version was narrated on the authority of Ka'b ibn 'Ujra and was documented in *Sahih al-Bukhari* and *Sahih Muslim* (quoted below) among other books of hadith and *fiqh*:

> حدثنا محمد بن المثنى، ومحمد بن بشار، - واللفظ لابن المثنى - قالا حدثنا محمد بن جعفر، حدثنا شعبة، عن الحكم، قال سمعت ابن أبي ليلى، قال لقيني كعب بن عجرة فقال ألا أهدي لك هدية خرج علينا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فقلنا قد عرفنا كيف نسلم عليك فكيف نصلي عليك قال: قُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ اللَّهُمَّ بَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ
>
> Ibn Abi Laila reported: Ka'b ibn 'Ujra met me and said: Should I not offer you a present (and added): The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) came to us and we said: We have learnt how to invoke peace upon you; (kindly tell us) how we should bless you. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Say:" O Allah: bless Muhammad and his family as Thou didst bless the family of Ibrahim. Verily Thou art Praiseworthy and Glorious, O Allah."
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 4, Hadith 70](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/70)</sub>

Its transliteration is:

> *Allāhumma salli 'ala Muhammad wa 'ala āli Muhammad kama salayta 'ala āli Ibrāhīm, innaka hamīdum majīd. Allāhumma bārik 'ala Muhammad wa 'ala āli Muhammad kama bārakta 'ala āli Ibrāhīm, innaka hamīdum majīd.*

The second version was narrated on the authority of Abu Humaid as-Sa'idi and was documented in *Sahih al-Bukhari* and *Sahih Muslim* (quoted below) among other books of hadith and *fiqh*:

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى التَّمِيمِيُّ، قَالَ قَرَأْتُ عَلَى مَالِكٍ عَنْ نُعَيْمِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ الْمُجْمِرِ، أَنَّ مُحَمَّدَ بْنَ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ زَيْدٍ الأَنْصَارِيَّ، - وَعَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ زَيْدٍ هُوَ الَّذِي كَانَ أُرِيَ النِّدَاءَ بِالصَّلاَةِ - أَخْبَرَهُ عَنْ أَبِي مَسْعُودٍ الأَنْصَارِيِّ قَالَ أَتَانَا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَنَحْنُ فِي مَجْلِسِ سَعْدِ بْنِ عُبَادَةَ فَقَالَ لَهُ بَشِيرُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ أَمَرَنَا اللَّهُ تَعَالَى أَنْ نُصَلِّيَ عَلَيْكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ فَكَيْفَ نُصَلِّي عَلَيْكَ قَالَ فَسَكَتَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم حَتَّى تَمَنَّيْنَا أَنَّهُ لَمْ يَسْأَلْهُ ثُمَّ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قُولُوا ‏ "‏ اللَّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا صَلَّيْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ وَبَارِكْ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَعَلَى آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ كَمَا بَارَكْتَ عَلَى آلِ إِبْرَاهِيمَ فِي الْعَالَمِينَ إِنَّكَ حَمِيدٌ مَجِيدٌ ‏.‏ وَالسَّلاَمُ كَمَا قَدْ عَلِمْتُمْ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Abdullah ibn Zaid-he who was shown the call (for prayer in a dream) narrated it on the authority of Abu Mas'ud al-Ansari who said: We were sitting in the company of Sa'id ibn 'Ubida when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) came to us. Bashir ibn S'ad said: Allah has commanded us to bless you. Messenger of Allah! But how should we bless you? He (the narrator) said: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) kept quiet (and we were so much perturbed over his silence) that we wished we had not asked him. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) then said: (For blessing me) say:" 0 Allah, bless Muhammad and the members of his household as Thou didst bless the mernbers of Ibrahim's household. Grant favours to Muhammad and the members of his household as Thou didst grant favours to the members of the household of Ibrahim in the world. Thou art indeed Praiseworthy and Glorious" ; and salutation as you know.
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 4, Hadith 69](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/69)</sub>

Its transliteration is

> *Allāhumma salli 'ala Muhammad wa 'ala āli Muhammad kama salayta 'ala āli Ibrāhīm, wa bārik 'ala Muhammad wa 'ala āli Muhammad kama bārakta 'ala āli Ibrāhīm fil-'ālamīn, innaka hamīdum majīd.*

It is recommended by scholars that one uses both forms at one stage or another, alternating between the two every now and then. The short version *"Allāhumma salli 'ala Muhammad wa 'ala āli Muhammad"* (Arabic: اللهم صل على محمد) is not a form that I have come across as an acceptable form of Durood.

Comment: Nope, in the first one in the original Hadith the words “Ibrāhīm wa ‘ala āli Ibrāhīm” seem to be added by you in the transliteration and in the second transliteration it seems to be a different version of the Durood-e-Ibrahīm all together, How can you explain this, O @III-AK-III?

Comment: @maounkhan, thank you for pointing this out. I removed the extra "Ibrāhīm" from the first transliteration and corrected the hadith number and text for the second one.